# How can I use ::before in Angular scss stylesheet?

Tags: css, angular, sass, styles

I've got that code in my scss file:

```css
#mainBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.imageBox::before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, #e91e63, #03a9f4);
  z-index: 99;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.imageBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;

  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

Everything is fine, but I can't make this ::before works. I was trying with ::ng-deep but it wasn't work.

EDIT:

```
<div id="mainBox">

  <div class="imageBox">
    <img src="../assets/images/loginPageDoctor.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="contentBox">
     Some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my HTML code. There are two containers for image and content.

Answer (score 0):

It should be placed after the `class` tag. In this example `p` is the tag for paragraph.

```
  p::before {
      margin-left: 2rem;
    }
```

Comment: Don't get it. How it is different from the code I posted?

Comment: Here .imageBox is a scss class?